# most accepted methods to validate an entity in silex framework

Tags: php, validation, symfony, dependency-injection, silex

I want to validate an entity but do not know the best place to do this. I put validation code in the setter method. What if I choose `Symfony\Component\Validator` for validation, how can I access the validator service? As far as I know, this means there is a dependency to the service.

```
$app['validator']->validateValue($title, new Assert\NotBlank());
```

And I think injecting dependency to an entity class is not a good approach, right? If so, how can you do this validation?

```
<?php
// AnExample/Entity/Book.php
namespace AnExample;

class Book
{
  private $isbn;
  private $title; // at leats 3 letters

  public function __set($name, $value) {
   ...
  }

  public function __get($name) {
   ...
  }

}
?>
```

Technically there are many ways, but what I'm looking for is the conventional one, a design pattern for this problem.

Comment: Have you tried adding validation to the form? That's the method I'm using.

Comment: NO, I've not. I'm not using a form. Input data may come from both API  and CLI. Even if I'm not creating any html, should I use form validation?

Comment: All my data comes from user input, so this method was fine for me. I also have no entities, I'm only using the DBAL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep things light, one solution might be using static `loadValidatorMetadata` method. You can read more [here](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/validator.html).